# What does the word 「やったる」 mean?

Tags: manga, dialects, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

Here is the sentence including the word. It is said by an old man who is cooking some food and planning to give it to a younger person who is in jail.

> ようし　わしゃあ**やったる**ぜ

I am not sure if it is a shorten form of 「やってやる」which means "Doing something for someone who is below than the speaker"

Is it still used nowadays in Kantou area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's short for やってやる. Please see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010) for the list of similar contractions. I think this contraction is common throughout Japan regardless of generation (but it sounds relatively masculine)

And `te-form + やる` means not only "to do something for someone" but also "dare to do something", "to do something proactively with an active effort", "to do something and show off (the result / one's power)" etc. See: [what does てやる mean when it is not used for giving?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14413/5010)

The sentence probably just means "I'll do that" (without "for someone").