# The nuance of "やってやる"

Tags: nuances

I've seen a few topics on "~てやる" here (I do apologise in advance if this question overlaps too much with any previous answered posts), but I have a specific question regarding the phrase "やってやる".

I was told by a fellow Japanese learner that "やってやる" is a casual way of saying "I'll do it for you" so the nuance is + "for someone". However, my textbook only lists the following definitions:

> To do it/ to give it a go

With no mention of doing something specifically "for someone".

Is the nuance indeed doing something "for someone" or is it just "I'll do it" regardless of whether your doing something for someone or not?

Comment: If you raise the level of formality and turn it into してあげる, does that help?

Comment: A short phrase like やってやる has ***so many*** meanings that are completely different from one another.  To discuss the nuance, you would need to provide the context/situation in which it is said.  Believe it or not, the phrase could mean from "I'll kill'em!" and "I'll **** her!" to "I will do it for you."

Comment: Might be related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14413/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36744/9831