# Is this phrase untranslatable?

Tags: translation, て-form

(For context, it's said by one character attacking another)
The phrase is 「やってやんよ」I've read somewhere that やます can mean 'to do/go' (google says the translation is 'I'll do it' But could it be one of those untranslatable things?

Comment: A comment under this post may help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52993/9831 `the phrase could mean from "I'll kill'em!" and ...`

Answer (score 3):

やってやんよ is a contracted form of **やってやるよ**.

- **やって**: the te-form of やる meaning "to do"
- **やる** (やん): やる meaning "to give", but as a subsidiary verb, it means "to do something to show one's ability" or "to do something for someone's sake"

  - [What does てやる mean when it is not used for giving?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14413/5010)
  - [What does the word 「やったる」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36744/5010)
- **よ**: a sentence-end particle

So the nuance of やってやんよ is either (or both) of "I'll do this *to prove my power*" or "I'll do this *for you if you want me to*". Something like this is typically said after the speaker has been provoked by someone, but it depends on the previous context. It's not the kind of phrase that can always be translated correctly without context (whish is probably why Google ignored the てやる part). But it's always possible to translate it to a similar English sentence if you understand the implication.

By the way, やます means nothing to me.

Comment: So how does the ん get into やん? Is it perhaps a contraction of やるの?

Comment: @user55600 ん does not turn into やん, but the second やる turned into やん. This sentence is basically `やって + やる + よ`, but `やる + よ` contracted into `やんよ`. There is no explanatory-の in this sentence. Do you know about [subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010)?