# Question about て- form verb ended with したる

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

It is a situation that 2 boys were going to fight.

A: いくぜ　やろう！

B: こいっ　ぶっころ**したるっ**

I know that て- form verb followed by したる or してある indicating a completed action in preparation of something. In this case, they were going to fight so there was no one killed. I would like to know why this form was used instead of　しておく. Probably, I misunderstood the concept.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14413/5010 and http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010

Answer (score 2):

In this case, したる is an abbreviated, and of course informal, form of **してやる**. For the meaning of て-form + やる, see No. 17 of [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/223431/meaning/m0u/).

Here, 17-イ is applied, so the concept of ぶっころしたる is like "I'm going to kill you" / "I'm killing you".